# How to set multiple shipping in Shopware?

Tags: shopware, shipping-method

How can i set multiple shipping options in Shopware ?

Like as below i want to set shipping

```
1 Option for UK standard shipping £3.75
2 Option for UK express Shipping £5.95
```

and these both should appear in front end for customers.

**I want to display like as with multiple options**
[image]

**And Shopware displaying like below**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create more than one shipping cost in the backend.Please make sure, that you allow countries and payments in the corresponding tabs of the shipping costs.

https://en-community.shopware.com/Shipping-costs_detail_831.html

Comment: I have tried according to given steps in above link but getting only 1 option not both

Comment: Since this works on every other shop, it seems to be a configuration issue. Please check both shipping costs again (active, payment assignment, country assignment, customergroups, shops, ...). The payment can only be changed on the /checkout/shippingPayment page.